# Very Basic Probability: Lottery Chances

Tags: probability

If each ticket for a lottery has a 1 in 258,890,850 chance... what happens if you buy 10 tickets?

Is it:

- A 10 in 258,890,850 chance?
- A 1 in 258,890,840 chance?
- A 1 in 25,889,085.0 chance?

What is the best way to represent the chances? This is very simple, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Assuming that you don't pick two tickets with the same numbers, 10/(258,890,850)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a $1$ in $258,890,850$ chance to win with one ticket, that is a chance of $$\frac{1}{258,890,850} $$ then to find out what happens with $10$ unique tickets you simply multiply your chance with one ticket by $10$. Thus the chance to win becomes $$ \frac{10}{258,890,850}=\frac{1}{25,889,085}$$
Thus both your first answer and third answer are correct, and both would be acceptable ways to write the probability of winning with $10$ tickets.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to look at it:

Suppose this is a Pick 6 lottery (it doesn't much matter the exact numbers),
and there are **N** possible sets of 6 numbers that can be chosen,
258,890,850 in your example.

Now suppose you buy 2 tickets: (1 2 3 4 5 6) and (7 8 9 10 11 12).

Each of those has a 1 in **N** chance of being the winner, and now you have a 
2 in **N** chance since that's how many sets of numbers you have.

And for any *n* tickets that you buy, you'll have an "*n* in **N**" chance of one of them being the winner.

In the extreme, if you buy N tickets, all different, you now have an **N** in **N**, or 100% chance of winning, which is fine if you can manage to buy all those tickets, the jackpot is bigger than **N**, and there is no chance you'll have to split the pot with another winning ticket.